# What is effect when I set up some self defined predisctor variables?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, random-forest

I run a random forest model on a dataset to assess the credit risk. I found the periodic income and periodic liability were important features in my estimator. Then I try to set a ratio metric which was periodic income/periodic liability which measured the relevant scale on these two variables. Then I found this ratio was also important but the model performance like f1 score, confusion matrix were not improved.

In my case here, does it mean the ratio was redundant and took no extra effect in enhancing the prediction? In math, periodic income , periodic liability and ratio represented different quantitative meaning.

Can I say in machine learning scope, if Variable A and B were all important from the fitting result, then the ratio of them or even any other algebraic operation on them can be expected as important as well but no extra contribution on the model fitting?

Could someone give me advice and thanks heaps.